# Simple div with header,footer and body

Tags: html, css, header, footer, fluid-layout

I need a simple `div` with `header,footer and body content.`

The `header` and `footer` needs to be `fixed` and the `height` of div should be `250px` or max `500px` and its `width` is `500px`
And my `body content` should be `fluid` so that it should extend the content.

`Header` and `footer` needs to be `40px.`

And I need a horizontal line after header and above footer.

I have done it but I am unable to set its footer as I am going nuts with the alignment.

Can anyone suggest me with this:

CSS:

```
mainbody
{
position:absolute;
Left:35%;
top:20%;
display:none;
height:250px;
width:500px;
margin-top: 0;
border:1px solid #fff;
box-shadow:0px 2px 7px #292929;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
background-color:#ffffff;
z-index:50;
}


.header
{
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 40px;
    width: 490px;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}


.footer
{
width:500px;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-top: 37px;
margin-left:-5px;
background-color: whiteSmoke;
border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;            
}
```

This is what I need:

[image]

Comment: @All-Thanks for your support guys you made me to think different each one in the diff way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to simplify your approach. I put the drop-shadow and rounded corners on a `div.container`, and then mirror the rounded corners as applicable (top and bottom) so you don't have blocky overlaps. I also added some `min-height` and `max-height` values, with `overflow: auto` on the `.mainbody` element.

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.mainbody,
.header,
.footer {
    padding: 5px;
}
.mainbody {
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 388px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.header {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.footer {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: whiteSmoke;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="mainbody">
        <p>Body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="mainbody">
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="mainbody">
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VzGAy/2/

Comment: And the `max-height` on `.mainbody` should be `max-height: 388px;`, so it doesn't push the `.footer` down before overflow/scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/VzGAy/2/

Comment: Note as well that the previous jsFiddles have a CSS Reset applied (*Normalized CSS* checkbox on the right). To see what it looks like without that applied, see: http://jsfiddle.net/VzGAy/3/

Comment: @Jared-Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: how to make it span whole page

Answer (score 3):

The `position:absolute` property removes your div from the natural flow of your document, thus leaving it to manual positioning that has to be modified every time. So, just let it flow naturally and contain your divs inside a container with the rounded effects you want, this way you can highly simplify your css and more easily manage your document, like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        header
    </div>
    <div class="mainbody">
        main body
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container:before, .container:after {
    display:table;
    content:"";
    zoom:1 /* ie fix */;
}

.container:after {
    clear:both;
}

.container {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.mainbody {
    height:250px;
    width:500px;
    border: solid #eee;
    border-width:1px 0;
}


.header, .footer {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
}


.footer {
    background-color: whiteSmoke;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n6pSm/

Comment: What's the point of the `:before`, `:after` and `clear: both`? I [agree a container helps](http://jsfiddle.net/VzGAy/2/), but I don't see what the value of the first class definitions is supposed to be.

Comment: @JaredFarrish inline [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/), so, proper containment.

Comment: I understand what's it's supposed to do; why have you included it [when it doesn't seem to have any affect](http://jsfiddle.net/n6pSm/1/)? Am I missing something that you're anticipating?

Comment: From the clearfix page: `Including the :before selector is not necessary to clear the floats, but it prevents top-margins from collapsing in modern browsers. This ensures that there is visual consistency with IE 6/7 when zoom:1 is applied.` So, proper containment/placement consistency across browsers is your answer.

Comment: I guess I'm just missing it, but that seems like circular logic. There's no floats to clear in the example markup.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Its all about proper containment, without it the container class would be incomplete. What we have here is a layout, once you start getting the content inside of the layout proper clearing and containment does become an issue, so i always compensate for that. So, a proper container would be incomplete without proper clearing, and it is why i add it everytime.

Comment: I can understand that (best practice); otherwise it looks out of place. Thank you for the explanation. `:)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish well, not out of place, i'd still call it proper containment, if its not properly cleared why even use a container class at all? a wrapper class would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

This could do what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/FZGL4/

```
.mainbody
{
    min-height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
}


.header
{
    height: 40px;
    width: 500px;
    border-bottom: #000 1px solid;

}


.footer
{
    height: 40px;
    width: 500px;
    border-top: #000 1px solid;       
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

dont know whether this would fit your needs .. but,check out.. http://jsfiddle.net/aFgDN/1/

```
.header
{
position:fixed;
height: 30px;
background-color: yellow;
width: 500px;
}
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.mainbody{
position:fixed;
top:30px;
bottom:40px;
min-height:250px;
width:500px;
border:1px solid black;
background-color:red;
}
.footer{
width:500px;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
height:40px;
background-color: blue;

}
```

This would be your html ..

```
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="mainbody"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

have removed other things from your css -- you can add it later..

Answer (score 1):

I made some tweaks to your CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cx4qG/