# Header/footer/main code

Tags: html, css

I am needing help creating code that includes a div for a #header, #footer, and #main. I'm just not sure where it goes in the code. I have created a simple html page with a css style sheet. I'm not asking for anyone to write the code for me as I am really trying to actually learn this for my class, but some guidance would be awesome. The page is a resume with my contact info in the header and a copyright notice in the footer. The resume content will go in the main section. Thank you so much for any help you can offer!

Here is what I had for the previous assignment that we are to build on.

**CSS Style Sheet...**

```
body {
background-color: rgb(184, 179, 173);
}

.header{

h1{
font-family:"Impact", Charcoal, "sans-serif";
color: rgb(217, 89, 0);
margin-left: 20px;
font-size:65px;
text-align: center;
}

h2{
font-family:"arial black", gadget, "sans-serif";
color: rgb(242, 125, 0);
margin-left: 20px;
font-size:40px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
}

p{
font-family:"arial", arial, "sans-serif";
color: rgb(51, 53, 36);
margin-left: 32px;
font-size:20px;
text-align: left;
text-indent:-32px

}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:230px;
    height:320px;
}
```

**HTML page...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JillBowman2.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Jill Bowman</h1>
<img  src="https://s26.postimg.org/9p6vuu5i1/JBowman.png" alt="Jill-Bowman-Photo">
<br>
<h2>Education</h2>
<p>Bachelor of Science - Elementary Education<br>
Oklahoma State University - Stillwater, OK<br>
May 2010</p>
<br>
<p>Master of Education - Educational Technology <br>
University of Arkansas - Fayetteville, AR<br>
Anticipated December 2018.</p>
<h2>Educational Experience</h2>
<br>
<p>6th Grade Math Teacher - McKinney, TX<br>
From August 2015 - June 2017 I was employed by McKinney Independent School District as a 6th grade math teacher at Dowell Middle School. During my time at Dowell I taught on-level, Pre-AP, and GT. I was the NJHS sponsor and coordinated a fundraising campaign that raised over $10,000 for the Leukemia and Lymphoma Society. I was also the Academic UIL coach for Calculator Applications and Number Sense. My students consistently placed in the top 5 in both events. In the 2016-2017 school year, 59% of my students scored at the highest level on the STAAR test.</p>
<br>
<p>8th Grade Math Teacher - Carrollton, TX<br>
From August 2014 - June 2015 I was employed by Carrollton-Farmers Branch Independent School District as an 8th grade math teacher at Dan F. Long Middle School. While at Long, I taught Algebra 1 and 8th grade math. I implemented a blended classroom with the use of 1-to-1 iPads. I was also the head cheer coach and StuCo sponsor at Long.</p>
<br>
<p>Middle School Math Teacher - Tulsa, OK<br>
From August 2012 - June 2014 I was employed by Tulsa Union Public School as a math teacher at the Union 6th/7th Grade Center. While at U6/7 I taught all levels of math to 6th and 7th grade. I was also the leader of two after school clubs. One of my clubs talked about current events and the other taught the students how to cook easy and healthy meals for their families. I was also the afternoon detention teacher. </p>
<br>
<p>7th Grade Math Teacher - Liberal, KS<br>
From August 2011-May 2012 I was employed by Liberal USD 480 as a 7th grade math teacher at West Middle School. While at WMS, I taught various levels of 7th grade math. I was also responsible for security at all sporting events. </p>
<br>
<p>6th Grade Core Teacher - Liberal, KS<br>
From August 2010 - May 2011 I was employed by Liberal USD 480 as a 6th grade core teacher at Cottonwood Intermediate School. I was responsible for teaching my students math, science, social studies, and language arts. While at CIS I worked for Project BEST which was an after school enrichment and remediation program. </p>
<br>
<h2>Showcase</h2>
<br>
<p>As a requirement for one of my master’s classes, I built a website with various technology tutorials. Please visit my page by clicking <a href="https://jeb029.wixsite.com/website"> here.</a>
<h2>Contact Me</h2>
<p>Feel free to contact me via <a href="mailto:jeb029@email.uark.edu">Email.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share any code that you already have?

Comment: edit your question with you code please

Comment: edited to include the code that I have so far. We were to do a basic html linked to a style sheet in the previous assignment. Now we are adding the div with the #header, #footer, and #main.....we previously did a CSS box model where we used the div, but I don't understand how to merge the two....This class if my first time to code so sorry I'm a complete newbie!

Comment: Please review [ask]. You appear to have forgotten to include an actual question. As it's unclear what exactly you're asking, this "question" should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you already have the style sheet referenced in your HTML file.  All you need to do here is add a div element, which is just a container, and "call" the various css definitions.  I think your intial attempt worked fine but you weren't exactly calling the header CSS definition:

```html
    <div class="header">Header</div>
```

At the end of the day, I'd just recommend you take a look at this if you still need help: [Simple div with header,footer and body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351045/simple-div-with-header-footer-and-body)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had looked at that link previously but I was having a hard time understanding it all.

Comment: No problem.  If my answer suffices, can you please mark it as your accepted answer?  Thank you in advance.